# I am not able to refresh terraform object

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using terraform to deploy a template (google_compute_instance_template) and MIG (google_compute_instance_group_manager) which is using the template. The problem which I am facing is updating the template. Once I try to change a network tag or something else I am receiving the following error:

```
Error: Error creating instance template: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/instanceTemplates/temp01' already exists, alreadyExists
```

I have to destroy the MIG and the template and redeploy terraform. Can I somehow update the template without destroying it?

PS
For the template I am using also:

```
    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to fix this issue ? I have exactly the same problem even tho i followed the terraform doc : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template#using-with-instance-group-manager

Comment: @zoey3 - Compute Engine instance templates cannot be modified. ***Instance templates are designed to create instances with identical configurations. So you cannot update an existing instance template or change an instance template after you create it.*** [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates#how_to_update_instance_templates).